# import and export an html tag in 2 js files

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, node.js

i've two html file linked to two js files. i wanna save a html tag from html1 with js1 in an Variable and export it .
then import it in js2 file and use it in html2

i tried so many ways and didnt work,
simply like this

exporting:

> html 1

```
        <div id="mainPageCont">
            <h2 id="defaultPage" style="text-align: center; margin: auto; width: 100%; height: 200; font-size: large; background-color: blue;">Default Main :))</h2>
        </div>
```

> js 1

```
let mainPageContainer = document.getElementById("mainPageCont")
export default mainPageContainer;
```

importing:

> html 2

```
        <div id="main-container"></div>
```

> js 2

```
    import mainPageContainer from './Pages/Main/mainScripts.js' 
    document.querySelector("#main-container").innerHTML = mainPageContainer
```

Comment: That's not what imports and exports are for or how they work.